# Date picker not showing correct Date in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, datepicker

Date picker not showing current date

this is the date picker code

```
@IBAction func Fromdate(_ sender: UIButton) {

        DatePicker.isHidden = false
        DatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SendLeaveLetterViewController.datepickcervalueschange1), for: .valueChanged)
    }


func datepickcervalueschange1(datepicker:UIDatePicker)
{


    DatePicker.datePickerMode = .date

    let dateformat1 = DateFormatter()

    dateformat1.dateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY"

    print("datepiker date ",DatePicker.date)


    dateformat1.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")! as TimeZone

    ===> problem hear  
    let selectdata1 = dateformat1.string(from:DatePicker.date)

    print("selectdate...\(selectdata1)")

    frombutton.setTitle(selectdata1, for: .normal)

}
```

I am getting output :

if I can click 12/08/2017 it showing after update

datepiker date  2017-08-12 07:00:21 +0000

selectdate...224-08-2017

pls help me ......

Comment: just remove this line:- dateformat1.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")! as TimeZone

Comment: By the way, why are you changing `datePickerMode` in this function? It should be called just once, upon initialization of `UIDatePicker`

Comment: "DD-MM-YYYY" is completely wrong, please look up the documentation.

Comment: after removing its sowing datepiker date  2017-02-04 07:17:05 +0000
selectdate...35-02-2017
same

Comment: set your dateformat as `"dd-MM-yyyy" `

Comment: "dd-MM-yyyy"  working fine thanks Bro.....!

Comment: @naga - welcome

Answer (score 1):

The dateFormat is wrong.
You should replace this :

```
dateformat1.dateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY"
```

By that :

```
dateformat1.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

Answer (score 1):

DateFormatter use a [Unicode Technical Standart](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) where

> d - Day of the month
>
> D - Day of year

So you should use

```
dateformat1.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```